# (Photoshop) How do i force layers' width and height and position to be in whole pixels

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop-elements

Hey i'm creating a layout using photoshop. Is there a way to force layers' position/dimensions to be in whole pixels when i scale/move them. For example, lets say i scaled a layer and its width was **72.34 px** and height **23.67 px** i want the width and height to be automatically rounded to the next closest pixel. So 73px for the width || 24px for the height. I would like this rounding to happen to layers' **x,y** positions too. Is this possible to do in Photoshop?

Answer (score 1):

- At first check the point size prefreneces, Go to Preferences > Units
  & Rulers > Point/Pica Size : it should be set on **PostScript** option.
- Try to no scaling all layers at the same
- There's not an option for making layers "Pixel Perfect" in photoshop,
  so perhaps you have to make layers pixel perfect one by one in polish
  process.